# Date and Time hidden form fields (Rails3)

Tags: ruby-on-rails

ive generated a scaffolding for my application. The DB has a date and time field that I want to set tu current date and time that the form is submitted.

I created at _form.html.erb

```
<div class="field">
    <%= f.label :t_date %><br />
    <%= f.date_select :t_date %>
  </div>

   <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :t_time %><br />
    <%= f.time_select :t_time %>
  </div>
```

But I dont want the user to set them, but the have to pass as a form argument.
I tought about hidden fields for them, but even if I set them as hidden, you could send a bad form trought json or a POST request am i right?
What would be the right way to pass the current date and time, save them to the db and showing them without the user notice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the form is used to create or update a model, you would just use the timestamping facility that Activerecord provides.

From the docs:

> Active Record automatically timestamps create and update operations if
>   the table has fields named created_at/created_on or
>   updated_at/updated_on.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you need to know the exact time the form was *loaded* rather than *submitted*, I'd recommend just adding the current date and time in your controller after you receive the form submission.  Nice and simple, and you get to sidestep the possibility of users submitting "malicious" dates.

Comment: How do I access the t_date and t_time variables from the controller? @object.t_time = Date.today?

Comment: @JuanCruzViotti - I would put them into the params hash before you call `Object.create` so you only save to your DB once: `params[:my_whatever][:t_time] = Date.today`.  But if you're just keeping track of when your models were created/updated, you should use Daniel's answer instead - it's way cleaner!